# Error in IBM Worklight v5.0 : Can not find variable WL

Tags: initialization, ibm-mobilefirst

My Sample html code in 'common' folder is :

```
*<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Define WL namespace.
        var WL = WL ? WL : {};
        WL.StaticAppProps = {
   "APP_DISPLAY_NAME": "AndroidShowNativePage",
   "APP_SERVICES_URL": "\/apps\/services\/",
   "APP_VERSION": "1.0",
   "ENVIRONMENT": "android",
   "LOGIN_DISPLAY_TYPE": "embedded",
   "WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL": "\/apps\/services\/api\/AndroidShowNativePage\/android\/"
};</script>

</head>
<body onload="WL.Client.init({})" id="content" style='display: none'>
<script >
function findItem()
{
   saveUserPref();
}
</script>

    <input type="button" name="locate" value="Locate" onclick="findItem();">

    <script src="js/My.js"></script>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>   
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    <script src="js/auth.js"></script>
</body>*
```

Javascript code (My.js) is :

```
*function saveUserPref()
{
    alert('In saveUserPerf');
    WL.Client.setUserPref('favList', 'Apple');  
    alert('3');
}
function getUserFavList()
{
    WL.Client.getUserPref("favList");
}*
```

Then I build and run in Android, then I click 'findItem' button  and I am getting the alert "In saveUserPref"  followed by this error :
 **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: WL **
It looks like when  WL.Client.getEnvironment() gets executed, WL is not found.

My Question is why I am getting WL as not found variable?

Am I missing any basic? What is basic concept of initialized WL namespace and other environment related parameters?

Comment: Please edit your question and state your Worklight 5.0.x version.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have both a reference to `initOptions.js` AND `WL.Client.init({})` in the `BODY` tag?

Remove the `onload=WL.Client.init({})` call from the `BODY` tag. Worklight initialization process takes place now in initOptions.js only.

Comment: Changed, but still not working. I dont't think this is the root cause.

Comment: Create a new app that all it does is WL.Client.getEnvironment. Does that work? If yes, the problem is in your app, and most of your app is unknown (you provide only glimpse of it).

Comment: Tried all possibilities, not working..BTW, what you mean by "you provide only glimpse of it"? Do you want me to send the app in archive?...let me know you where can I send?

Comment: Yes, pleaes do. put it in Dropbox and give me a link. Note that in the common folder that's not how the HTML is supposed to look like at all....